# Swift call Objective-C wrapper function containing blocks

Tags: objective-c, swift, block, wrapper

I have an Objective-C wrapper (ObjCWrapper.h and ObjCWrapper.m) with prototype

```
+ (void) login:(NSString *)username andPassword:(NSString *)password andErrorBlock:(SuccessBlock)errorBlock andSuccessBlock:(SuccessBlock)successBlock;
```

With typedef

```
typedef void (^SuccessBlock)(NSString *);
```

and implementation

```
+ (void)login:(NSString *)username andPassword:(NSString *)password andErrorBlock:(SuccessBlock)errorBlock andSuccessBlock:(SuccessBlock)successBlock
{
    // do stuff like
    successBlock(@"test");
}
```

From my swift view controller (ViewController.swift), I call the login function:

```
ObjCWrapper.login("abc", andPassword: "abc",
        andErrorBlock:
        {
            (error:String) -> Void in
            println();
        },
        andSuccessBlock:
        {
            (map:String) -> Void in
            println();
        }
    )
```

But I get error:

**Cannot invoke 'login' with an argument list of type '(String, andPassword: String, andErrorBlock:(String)->void, andSuccessBlock:(String)->void)'**

Searching in google says that I am passing some invalid types in the arguments, but I can't find anything wrong in the code. Removing the blocks from the function makes the code work, so I guess it is something related on the way of calling a block function.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: PS, don't use 'and' in Objective-C method name this way, refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF

Comment: @pinxue great, thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing

```
let username = "username" //usernameField.text
let password = "password" //passwordField.text

        ObjCWrapper.login(username, andPassword: password,
            andErrorBlock:
            {
                (map) -> Void in
                // stuff
            })
            {
                (map) -> Void in
                // stuff
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth adding nullability specifiers to your completion block:

```
typedef void (^SuccessBlock)( NSString * _Nonnull );
```

And to the method itself:

```
+ (void) login:(nonnull NSString *)username andPassword:(nonnull NSString *)password andErrorBlock:(nullable SuccessBlock)errorBlock andSuccessBlock:(nullable SuccessBlock)successBlock;
```

Then you should be able to call your method in Swift:

```
        ObjCWrapper.login("login", andPassword: "pass", andErrorBlock: { (error:String) -> Void in
        //error handling
        }) { (map:String) -> Void in
            //other stuff
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Adam, thanks a lot for the help. But I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Obj-C NSString != Swift String
With other word, you pass a String where a NSString is expected.
Casting it down should solve that.